# How to run Wireshark in the background without the GUI?

Tags: macos, window-manager, command-line, x11

I am trying to run Wireshark on Mac OS X in the background. I installed the command line utilities, and so I am able to start Wireshark and capture packets using the command line.

The only thing I want now is to run it in the background, without the X11 icon in the Dock or seeing Wireshark's window. I believe it is possible, but can't find anything in Wireshark's docs.

Maybe another approach would be to hide the icon?

If anybody has already did this or has an idea…

Comment: BTW - please don't post questions here *and* at [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/227526/how-to-run-wireshark-on-the-background-without-the-gui).

Answer (score 4):

As initially [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567539/how-to-run-wireshark-on-the-background-without-the-gui/4567550#4567550):

> As far as I remember TShark comes with all distributions of Wireshark. This runs from the command line. The documentation for it is here: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html
>
> And there's some examples on how to use it here: http://www.codealias.info/technotes/the_tshark_capture_and_filter_example_page

— [David Hewitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467133/david-hewitt)

Answer (score 3):

There is also a complete alternative in the form of [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/), which comes by default on many OS X installs. The syntax is different, but it's command-line only, and is invaluable in a smaller/command line only environment.

It must be run as root, otherwise undo `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

As @VxJasonxV said you can use [TCPDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and if you don't want the output show on terminal can use `>> filename` to TCPDump save result on your desired file.

you can use TCPDump with many options but I think this was the best one:

```
tcpdump -n -v -S -i en1 tcp
```

en1: interface that you assign IPv4

-v: produce (slightly more) verbose output

-S: Print absolute, rather than relative, TCP sequence numbers.

-n: Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names.

-i: Listen on interface.

but this save the output that was not readable by human if you want to process the output that was readable by human you must use [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

the command that you must use is some thing like this:

```
tshark -r ~/home/myHome/Desktop/file_name(produce by tcpdump) -R "ip.src==172.16.13.128" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.id -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.analysis.ack_rtt -E header=y > ~/home/myHome/Desktop/file_name.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run it in `screen`, or in a virtual X11 session (Xvfb) that is not displaying to your monitor.